# implicit conversion from object to boolean

Tags: vb.net, linq

I keep getting this exception "implicit conversion from object to boolean"  for below expression how do i get rid of it?

```
 Dim objRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From myRow As DataRow In objDS.Tables(0).AsEnumerable Where myRow.Item(PERSON_ID_LIST) = personid).Cast(of DataRow)
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell us where the error is happening in your code so we don't have to guess?

Comment: Happens at the where clause "  Where myRow.Item(PERSON_ID_LIST) = personid)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 Dim objRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = 
    From myRow As DataRow In objDS.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
    Where myRow.Field(Of Int32)("PERSON_ID_LIST") = personid
```

otherwise you have to tell us what `PERSON_ID_LIST` is.